# While using iTextSharp, I can read text from only few PDFs not every PDF. I am using LocationTextExtractionStrategy

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I provide coordinates of the rectangle which enclose the area of where i have to read text. I am calculating the coordinates assuming it is a 72 PPI PDF file. For some reason I could only read the text from PDFs created with microsoft word and having size 3.5 MB. I can't read the text from files created with ghostscript and having size at around 1 MB even though both have the same amount of pages. I think I am having problem getting the true coordinates, I calculate coordinates by using GIMP and while doing it I have to set the PPI of the PDF. Can you tell me what can i do?

Comment: You aren't providing the correct information in your question. Please rephrase it. The file size of the files is irrelevant: remove it from your question. Calculating coordinates using GIMP is... awkward. What you need is the page size! Use [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) to find the difference in `/MediaBox`. Your assumption that PDF has a resolution (e.g. 72 PPI) is wrong. All of this makes that your question can't be answered. If I were a computer, I'd reply: *can't compute, too many errors in your question!*

Comment: +1 for all of what @BrunoLowagie said, I just want to add that without code and sample PDFs we can't really help you. We have no idea what you're actually doing and we have no idea if you are working on valid PDF files (and just because Adobe Reader opens a PDF doesn't mean it is actually valid).

Comment: You might start by trying to extract all text from those pdfs. If that works, your issue likely is the calculation of coordinates. If it doesn't, the issue may be in the pdfs themselves.